# MS form is not loading the second time onwards and gives the console error

Tags: forms, ms-forms

Issue: MS form is not loading the second time onwards and gives the below error.

Uncaught Error: MsCrmFormLoader is already defined, make sure Dynamics 365 Marketing loader.js script is not included twice in the page
at form-loader.js?v=x
at form-loader.js?v=x

We have used some react components to bind the script tag and form div.
[image]

We even tried to just bind the div content right after the script tag. Basically based on the error message, we do not touch the script tag to fix the console error. Still, the form does not load.

We don't want to refresh the page instead update the DOM with the script and div form below it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling the whole day with this. Found the solution.
This is on React , but you get the idea:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this is a hack to make sure the newsletter form is loaded
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    const scriptTracker = document.createElement('script');

    const isScriptLoaded = window.MsCrmMkt !== undefined;
    if (!isScriptLoaded) {
      script.src =
        '<src>';
      script.async = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
      window.MsCrmMkt = undefined;
    };
  }, []);
```

the most important part is

```html
window.MsCrmMkt = undefined;
```

This makes sure the object is being deleted.

That's it :)

Comment: Any idea how to use the events in this method? Like `window.MsCrmMkt.MsCrmFormLoader.on("afterFormLoad", ... )`

Comment: @martinedwards did you figure out how to use it? I've got the same question as you

Comment: I wasn't able to find it directly, but I was able to access the form with the querySelector `.d365-mkt-for .one-column-form`. As the form is properly loaded into the page, not just in an iframe. Then I could get lower level form fields with more specific querySelectors, and also work out when the form was submitted with document.querySelector(".d365-mkt-for .one-column-form").addEventListener("submit", async () => { ... }). Hope that helps a bit.